# Marshal void * (handle) as return paramater

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling

An unmanaged DLL provides the (simplified) function

```
int GetHandle(void* handle)
{
   int result = AssignHandle(&handle);
   return result;
}
```

Which assigns a handle and returns a result code.

How do I have to marshal the handle output parameter, such that I can use this handle in C# code?

The snippet

```
class Program
{
       [DllImport("unmanaged", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       extern static in GetHandle(out IntPtr s7DosHandle)
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           IntPtr handle;
           GetHandle(out handle);
       }
}
```

Correctly assigns a non-null handle in `GetHandle` (which I can verify by debugging) but the out parameter in the .NET main function is null.

Comment: The bug is in `GetHandle`. It never writes to the `handle` parameter. (It passes the address of `handle` to a second `GetHandle()`, which updates `handle`, but that is an update to the local. It has no effect on the caller's copy of `handle`.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using ref instead of out? Out would be used if function returned void**. Additionally, which dll are you referencing? "unmanaged" should be something like "library.dll"

Comment: `GetHandle(void** handle)` so that the function can receive the *address* of the C# variable, not its *value*.